# Python class multiple initialization definition based on where it is initialized

Tags: python

What i want to do is make an object do different initializations based on where it is instanciated.

For example

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
    def __init2__(self):
        self.a = 2
```

So that the normal init is run when the class Test is called on it's own

```
t = Test()
print(t.a)
>>> 1
```

And when it is on a list it runs inside a List it runs the second init

```
t = [Test()]
print(t[0].a)
>>> 2
```

Is this possible in python?

Comment: This perl idiom is not available in python

Comment: 1. It would be crazy hard. 2. Why should `Test` care how it was initialized? sounds like a terrible design.  What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @DeepSpace “Impossible” is a strong word, with the right amount of introspection and monkey patching it’s probably doable. It’d still be insane though.

Comment: @deceze Indeed..

Comment: Not possible in any sane way, and it sounds like a bad fundamental design.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different approach, and just use a @classmethod as a factory method that creates an instance for the specific case:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, a=1):
        self.a = a

    @classmethod
    def in_list(cls):
        return cls(2)
```

so, in the list you can call:

```
t = [Test.in_list()]
print(t[0].a)
>>> 2
```